# Convolution of Pareto Random Variables

Tags: probability, convolution, pareto-distribution

Define $X$ ~ Pareto($a$) and $Y$ ~ Pareto($b$), meaning $f_X (x) = ax^{-a + 1}$ for $x \geq 1$ and $f_Y (y) = by^{-b + 1}$ for $y \geq 1$.

Assuming that $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, how would I find the density of $Z = X + Y$ and $W = Z - Y$.

Comment: Are you after the joint density of Z and W or their marginal densities? (What are you using it for?) For $Z$, take a look [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115291/what-distribution-results-in-adding-two-pareto-distributions).

Comment: The marginal distribution of $W = Z-Y = (X+Y)-Y = X$ is particularly easy to find. :-)

Comment: The density given $f_X (x) = ax^{-a + 1}$ is not Pareto (nor likely a valid density). Pareto for $x>1$ would be $f(x) = ax^{-(a+1)}$