# What is the CDF of sum of 2 Pareto random variables?

Tags: probability, distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, iid

Assume we have two independent, random variables, $X$ and $Y$ which follow the same Pareto distribution, i.e.:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^{2}}, x > 1$

Given that - what would be the joint probability $P(X + Y < a)$ of those variables? And generally speaking - how to obtain the CDF of $S = X + Y$?

Comment: When they're independent, the relevant integral of the joint density reduces to a convolution of the densities. For the general continuous case see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions immediately before the section labelled "Example Derivation": $f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\, f_Y(z-x)\, dx$. In some cases properties of generating functions (pgfs, mgfs, characteristic functions, cumulant generating functions) might be used instead.

Comment: The case of two Paretos with different parameter is covered here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115291/what-distribution-results-in-adding-two-pareto-distributions  (of course one can set $a=b$ there at least).

Comment: For identically-distributed Pareto variates see C. M. Ramsay (2006), "The Distribution of Sums of Certain I.I.D. Pareto Variates,"
Communication in Statistics- Theory and Methods 35(3):395-405

Comment: I think it would be splendid for the OP to submit the general solution to this exercise, in terms of Hypergemetric2F1 functions, and see what the marker makes of it.

Comment: @wolfies There's no need, because in this case the hypergeometric functions simplify: the integral has an elementary solution as a rational function of $a$ and $\log(a-1).$ Perhaps the easiest way to find it is to compute the convolution of the densities with partial fractions.  The CDF is found in a similar manner.

Comment: Sure - I am aware of that, having solved it before posting my comment. That is precisely why I think it would be splendid to submit the general solution: above and beyond (like Star Trek).